# Is there a Java standard library to directly construct PrivateKey and PublicKey objects from key files generated by ssh-keygen?

Tags: java

I would like to use id_rsa and id_rsa.pub to create a challenge-response login system for an application in Java. Towards this purpose, I want to be able to construct `PublicKey` and `PrivateKey` from id_rsa and id_rsa.pub.

The direct approach would be to parse these in the way I would normally parse a text file, and then manually construct the appropriate java.security data structures for signing and verifying in the client and server.

Is there a standard library shortcut that will ingest these files directly?

Comment: Don't know about a library, but JSch has functionality to read in a `KeyPair` so you could browse through the (BSD licensed) source code to find the place where it is used. Just an idea, not directly an answer, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The closest and easiest way I know, would be to use [The Legion of the Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html) Java API with something like this -

```
// Just for the public / private key files...
private static String readFileAsString(
    String filePath) throws java.io.IOException {

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(100);
  BufferedReader reader = null;
  try {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
        filePath));
    int fileIn;
    while ((fileIn = reader.read()) != -1) {
      sb.append((char) fileIn);
    }
  } finally {
    reader.close();
  }
  return sb.toString();
}

// Add the SecurityProvider and a Base64 Decoder (Once)
Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
BASE64Decoder b64 = new BASE64Decoder();

// For the publicKey
String publicKeyString = readFileAsString(publicKeyFileName);
AsymmetricKeyParameter publicKey =
  (AsymmetricKeyParameter) PublicKeyFactory.createKey(b64.decodeBuffer(publicKeyString));

// For the privateKey
String privateKeyString = readFileAsString(privateKeyFilename);
AsymmetricKeyParameter privateKey =
  (AsymmetricKeyParameter) PrivateKeyFactory.createKey(b64.decodeBuffer(privateKeyString));
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, I just wrote it: [openssh-java](https://github.com/fommil/openssh-java). :-)